# different widgets for different pages and posts

Tags: php, wordpress, post, widget, blogs

my blog page in Wordpress is using a specific widget but I wanted to use different widget for a post in the blog.

I used an example (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1308851) to write my code in sidebar.php.

```
<?php

if ( 'content' != $current_layout ) :
?>
    <?php   
    //for rest of posts
    if (is_active_sidebar('blog_widget_area') ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="blog_widget_area bordered" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'blog_widget_area' ); ?>

        </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
    <?php endif;

    //for specific post "Loyalty Program Trends in the Restaurant Industry"
    if (is_active_sidebar('loyalty_programs_widget_area') && is_single('4063') ) : ?>
            <div id="secondary" class="blog_widget_area bordered" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'loyalty_programs_widget_area' ); ?>
            </div>      
    <?php endif;

?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

However, I couldn't get the second widget to display in that specific post....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

Before trying below solution make sure some data/widget already loading on sideabar
loyalty_programs_widget_area.

solution 1

```
// use array inside is_single function
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('loyalty_programs_widget_area') && 
          is_single( array('4063','4063-page-name-here') )   ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

solution 2

```
// put separate if check inside sidebar
<?php if (is_active_sidebar('loyalty_programs_widget_area') ) : ?>

      if( is_single('4063') ) {  } or
      if( is_single(array('4063','pagename')) ) {  }

<?php endif; ?>
```

Other possible solutions:

Try:

-deactivating ALL plugins temporarily to narrow down and possibly fix the problem . If the problem goes away, activate them individually to find the culprit?

-switching to the default theme (Twenty Ten) for a moment by renaming your current theme's folder in wp-content/themes. The idea is to force WordPress to fall back to the default theme to rule out any theme-specific issue?

For further details read official documentation regarding " sidebar "
Note:
is_single() offer different other ways to check post id or name(when permalink isenabled)

```
- is_single(array(17,'beef-stew','Irish Stew'));
- is_single('17'); or is_single(17);
```

Try this code below:

```
<?php // only show on 31 post not any other. ?>
<?php if (  is_single('31') ) { ?>


        <?php // if blog_widget_area2 is active then show otherwise don't :) ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'blog_widget_area2' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="template_2_widget_area bordered">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar("blog_widget_area2"); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>


<?php }else{  // otherwise load this sidebar ?>


    <div class="template_2_widget_area bordered">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar("blog_widget_area"); ?>
    </div>



<?php } ?>
```

Comment: It's not working. I did make sure that both widgets are loaded with different stuff. However, I think I might know what the problem might be. It's probably the <?php before the second widget code? I noticed that when I added the <?php (notice that the original code doesn't have <?php before the second widget code), the blog page doesn't display the sidebar at all but the posts do. So how do I format the code so that the blog pages and its posts display one sidebar/widget but this certain post display a different sidebar/widget?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of codewizz (Thanks codewizz!), we got it to work. The things we need to change is to move the code over from sidebar.php to single.php. However, the way it's coded, it displays both the first widget and the second widget on the post's sidebar.

So he suggested that I use http://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/. And now it works.

Additionally, if one want to start from scratch, you should use that code

```
<?php // only show on 31 post not any other. ?>
<?php if (  is_single('31') ) { ?>


        <?php // if blog_widget_area2 is active then show otherwise don't :) ?>
        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'blog_widget_area2' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="template_2_widget_area bordered">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar("blog_widget_area2"); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>


<?php }else{  // otherwise load this sidebar ?>


    <div class="template_2_widget_area bordered">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar("blog_widget_area"); ?>
    </div>



<?php } ?>
```